# CakePHP Forms, where to find and how to modify?

Tags: forms, cakephp, select

I'm currently new to cakephp and I just want to ask how can I accomplish this,

[image]

a select box in which I'm the one determining its options,

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('treat', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
```

or how can I trace the code above to know where in the MVC did he determine his options for his selectbox. tnx

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: The controllers action has set the `$treats` variable for the view. So you should check your Controllers code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SOS as suggested by @ndm read up on the [Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html).

There are generally two ways to pass the options to a select via the Form Helper.

First if you [have baked the application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) the contents of the select could be in the DB.
The Form Helper recognizes [Model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) and builds the forms accordingly.Thus the contents of the select should be in the DB. For example if you have **User** belongsTo/hasOne **UserType**, the userTypes select will be populated from the DB table for userTypes.

The other way is as was already said, but unclear:

one can directly pass the options parameter of the `Form->input()` function.

There is another function that creates selects via the FormHelper: `select()`.
Check it [here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-FormHelper.html#_select)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code to define the options -

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('treat', array(
               'class' => 'form-control',
               'type' => 'select',
               'options' => array(
                               '1' => 'option 1',
                               '2' => 'option 2'
                            )
)); ?>
```

Just specify the options in the options array. you can also specify the blank option in that by writing `'empty'=>'Please Select'` in the array list.